Understanding nrounds in XGboost
I do not understand the parameter nrounds. I am working in R and using the package xgboost to create an 'extreme' gradient boost regression model.
There is a parameter called nrounds and my understanding of it was that it sets the number of trees in your gradient boosted model (also referred to as boosting iterations). However when I set nrounds = 0, I do not get that all predictions are equal to the base_score (initial guess in a gradient boosted model).
Why is that?
Note:
It is not that I want an xgboost model with 0 trees, but I tried it to sanity check my understanding of nrounds.
I have a data.frame that I transform to an xgb.DMatrix and then I train the model:
params <- list(objective = "reg:squarederror", eval_metric = "rmse", base_score = 0.5)

bst_model <- xgb.train(params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 0, verbose = 1)

Using predict I get:
pred <- predict(bst_model, newdata = dtrain)
print(pred[1:10])

[1] 1052663  874001 1498940 1991579 2316396 1086949  874001 1432935 1086949 2351261

Where I expected:
[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5


You are predicting a numeric feature with numeric regression metrics like rmse but expect a base score of 0.5? Isn't it the metric and objective which are not the correct ones/or your expected score?

@Yacine Hajji I don't expect a base_score of 0.5, but it is the default base_score in xgboost (I wrote base_score = 0.5 explicitly, but you can omit it). I just wanted to check if the prediction using nrounds = 0 was equal to the base_score, whatever the base_score is set to be - but not only is it not equal to the base_score, the predictions are not all equal either, so what is nrounds, if not number of trees?

From documentation, I have the same information. An nround of 1 would be the first tree, and any additional ones would be boosted trees. I don't know why you don't get similar base score but I would explore if you get these scores when using binary endpoint and adapted metric. Because to me 0.5 looks like a threshold for binary classification

@Yacine Hajji Base_score 0.5 is default for XGBoost, even for regression - and yes, to me it also looks like it would be meant for classification. I tried changing the base_score to the standard for gradient boosted regression, which is just the average of the target. Didn't matter though.

Setting nrounds = 0 doesn’t mean the model will use the base score for predictions. Instead, it means no boosting iterations will be performed, but the model still uses the initial guess based on the data provided.
Below are 2 points you need to complete your understanding

Initial Guess: The base_score is used as an initial guess, but when nrounds = 0, the model doesn’t perform any boosting iterations. The predictions you see are likely influenced by the initial state of the model and the data provided.

Data Influence: Even without boosting iterations, the model might still be influenced by the data structure and the initial state of the model parameters.


for addtional infor refer :https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html

Hmm, I will read the documentation, thanks.
